# How can I display objects from linked list JAVA

Tags: java

I would like some help in displaying objects that I have added to a linked list. Now the display function works when I return data at a specific position in the list. However I can not print any information from the whole list. I tried using a for loop and calling my function that allowed me to print the information at a specific position but all that did was print the last element. I have attached my code below:

WordList.java

```
// Returns the data at the specified position in the list.
protected Word get(int pos){
    if (head == null) throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    Node<Word> temp = head;
    for (int k = 0; k < pos; k++) temp = temp.getNext();
        if( temp == null) throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
        return temp.getData();
}

// Displays the word in the list
protected void display(){
    Node<Word> temp = head;
    for (int k = 0; k < getListSize(); k++)
        System.out.println(k);
        /*if(temp == null) throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();*/
        temp.getData();
        temp = temp.getNext();
}
```

Comment: This is a rather wasteful implementation: each iteration traverses the entire list up to the current index, so the number of calls of `next()` grows as an arithmetic progression. The number of times you call `next()` to print the list of `N` items is equal to `N*(N-1)/2`, while theoretically you should be able to do it in only `N` calls.

In addition, your `get` method does not guard against a situation when `pos` is greater than the length of the list; you get an exception when this happens.

Comment: Your indentation is possibly inconsistent with the intended semantics.  Please replace all tabs in the code section of your post with the proper number of blanks to make the indentation reflect your intention.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Good point about the pos being out of bounds error. I will add that to the method. What I don't get is what are you talking about wasteful implementation?

Comment: @Jim Garrison I tried to add numbers to the indentation but I could not add them through edit.

Comment: @user2251229 I thought that you were using `get(k)` in the implementation of `display()`, which would be wasteful. However, since you're using `getData`, not `get(k)`, your solution is not wasteful - just add curly braces as needed. Perhaps you could further optimize by iterating until you hit `temp == null`, rather than computing length and iterating `k` times.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing brackets around the body of your `for` loop:

```
protected void display(){
    Node<Word> temp = head;
    for (int k = 0; k < getListSize(); k++) {
        System.out.println(k);
        Word word = temp.getData();
        /* print word */
        temp = temp.getNext();
    }
}
```

Comment: I have a display method for word, but when I call it in the above, I get that I have to type cast word. The issue here is when I type cast it, eclipse adds a WordList<Word> typecast. Which gives me this error: The method display() is undefined for the type Word. Which is not true because I have a display method in my word class which basically prints out the id, word, definition, word category, and word difficulty. Basically I am trying to make a game similar to the lightning round in wheel of fortune. Which eventually pick words from a list based on id, category, and difficulty.

Comment: @user2251229 - What type of argument does your display method require?  I have no idea what types your various methods require or return; I was inferring a type from the code you posted.

Comment: I was hoping for no type to be returned but I have also tried Word.

Comment: @user2251229 - So you're trying to call `word.display()` and it complains that the method doesn't exist? Perhaps it's not `public`?

Comment: No it was set to protected. That shouldn't make a difference though as all my other methods are protected and they are accessible.

Comment: @user2251229 - Please edit your question to show the code for which there's a compiler error and the exact error message.